# Linq to Entities, random order

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

How do i return matching entities in a random order?
Just to be clear this is Entity Framework stuff and LINQ to Entities.

(air code)

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> results = from en in context.MyEntity
                                where en.type == myTypeVar
                                orderby ?????
                                select en;
```

Thanks

**Edit:**
I tried adding this to the context:

```
public Guid Random()
{
    return new Guid();
}
```

And using this query:

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> results = from en in context.MyEntity
                                where en.type == myTypeVar
                                orderby context.Random()
                                select en;
```

But i got this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid Random()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression..
```

**Edit (Current code):**

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> results = (from en in context.MyEntity
                                 where en.type == myTypeVar
                                 orderby context.Random()
                                 select en).AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The simple solution would be creating an array (or a `List<T>`) and than randomize its indexes.

EDIT:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Randomize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
  var array = source.ToArray();
  // randomize indexes (several approaches are possible)
  return array;
}
```

EDIT: Personally, I find the answer of Jon Skeet is more elegant:

```
var results = from ... in ... where ... orderby Guid.NewGuid() select ...
```

And sure, you can take a random number generator instead of `Guid.NewGuid()`.

Comment: Hi toro, Sorry, I'm not seeing what method to use on a List<T>, could you elaborate? thanks.

Comment: There isn't a framework method to do this.  I suggest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: Thanks mquander, that's what I was after.

Comment: I want to do this against millions of rows and so can't realistically bring all those entities into my context and start sorting them.  You can do this in the database using a variation of Jon's answer I posted below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order/4120132#4120132

Comment: Ordering by an unstable ranking function looks unsafe. Depending on the underlying sort algorithm, it may leads to bugs. See [this blog](https://lostechies.com/patricklioi/2013/09/14/shufflin-aint-sortin/) for details and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7952147/1178314) for a resulting bug case.

Comment: I wouldn't do it either because shuffling is an O(n) algorithm, and sorting is an O(n log n) one.

Answer (score 56):

A simple way of doing this is to order by `Guid.NewGuid()` but then the ordering happens on the client side. You may be able to persuade EF to do something random on the server side, but that's not necessarily simple - and doing it using "order by random number" [is apparently broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952147).

To make the ordering happen on the .NET side instead of in EF, you need `AsEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<MyEntity> results = context.MyEntity
                                       .Where(en => en.type == myTypeVar)
                                       .AsEnumerable()
                                       .OrderBy(en => context.Random());
```

It would be better to get the *unordered* version in a list and then shuffle that though.

```
Random rnd = ...; // Assume a suitable Random instance
List<MyEntity> results = context.MyEntity
                                .Where(en => en.type == myTypeVar)
                                .ToList();

results.Shuffle(rnd); // Assuming an extension method on List<T>
```

Shuffling is more efficient than sorting, aside from anything else.
See my [article on randomness](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) for details about acquiring an appropriate `Random` instance though. There are lots of Fisher-Yates shuffle implementations available on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hi Jon, I tried this, but couldn't get it working - see my edit. Thanks Nath

Comment: I don't see a .ToEnumerable() am I missing a namespace?

Comment: Hi Jon, I still get the same error as above with that change. Also the .OrderBy(context => context.Random()); line doesn't work as I get an error about redifining the context. I'll update my q with my latest query. Thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry - this is what comes of trying to answer in tiny bits of free time. The AsEnumerable() should be fine, but the lambda expression was broken. Try it now.

Comment: No worries, your help is appreciated. :o) I'm just commenting out my changes from Toro's answer and I'm giving it a go.

Comment: doesn't seem to give a random result tho.

Comment: Maybe it's new in EF4, but you can do this in the DB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order/4120132#4120132

Comment: @DeletedAccount, this technique does give random results for me at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order/4120132#4120132

Comment: Guid.newGuid() would be a relatively heavy way of randomising as a Guid is held in memory as 128-bits, better would be a int at 32-bit or double at 64-bits, though Guid.newGuid() will probably provide a more realistically random mix

Comment: [Professional ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway/dp/1118794753/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409025449&sr=8-1&keywords=professional+asp.net+mvc+5) gives the credit to this Jon Skeet's answer in Page 228.

Comment: Ordering by an unstable ranking function looks unsafe. Depending on the underlying sort algorithm, it may leads to bugs. See [this blog](https://lostechies.com/patricklioi/2013/09/14/shufflin-aint-sortin/) for details and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7952147/1178314) for a resulting bug case.

Comment: @Frederic: OrderBy in LINQ to Objects only evaluates the key projection once per element. It's certainly not what I'd use myself these days though - will edit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this info. The bug case occurs in linq-to-entities, not linq-to-objects. But since current EF supports NewGuid, many dev remove the AsEnumerable to get it ordered DB side. Then in case of includes in their queries, they may get duplicated results with EF 6.

Comment: @Frederic: Right. I'll edit the first sentence to indicate that.

Answer (score 43):

Jon's answer is helpful, but actually you *can* have the DB do the ordering using `Guid` and Linq to Entities (at least, you can in EF4):

```
from e in MyEntities
orderby Guid.NewGuid()
select e
```

This generates SQL resembling:

```
SELECT
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Column1] AS [Column1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    NEWID() AS [C1],                     -- Guid created here
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Column1] AS [Column1],
    FROM [dbo].[MyEntities] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC             -- Used for sorting here
```

In my testing, using `Take(10)` on the resulting query (converts to `TOP 10` in SQL), the query ran consistently between 0.42 and 0.46 sec against a table with 1,794,785 rows.  No idea whether SQL Server does any kind of optimisation on this or whether it generated a GUID for *every* row in that table.  Either way, that would be considerably faster than bringing all those rows into my process and trying to sort them there.

Comment: Note: If you run this code in LinqPad, and it doesn't work, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20953863/740639

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7952147/1178314), it is unfortunately broken. It looks like `OrderBy` assumes the ranking function to be stable, which is not the case with a random generator. Linq to entities translate this to a sql query which may get different ranking for the same entity (as soon as your queries use `Include`). Then it causes the entity to get duplicated in the result list.

Answer (score 4):

The `NewGuid` hack for sorting it server side unfortunately causes entities to get duplicated in case of joins (or eager fetching includes).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7952147/1178314) about this issue.

To overcome this issue, you may use instead of `NewGuid` a sql `checksum` on some unique value computed server side, with a random seed computed once client side to randomize it. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31245404/1178314) on previously linked question.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions provided here execute on the client. If you want something that executes on the server, [here is a solution for LINQ to SQL](http://linqinaction.net/blogs/main/archive/2008/01/10/randomizing-linq-to-sql-queries.aspx) that you can convert to Entity Framework.

Comment: This solution may cause execution on the server, but it also requires that you have access to setup Functions and Views on the SQL box itself.

Answer (score 1):

lolo_house has a really neat, simple and generic solution. You just need to put the code in a separate static class to make it work.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SpanishDrills.Utilities
{
    public static class LinqHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Randomize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> pCol)
        {
            List<T> lResultado = new List<T>();
            List<T> lLista = pCol.ToList();
            Random lRandom = new Random();
            int lintPos = 0;

            while (lLista.Count > 0)
            {
                lintPos = lRandom.Next(lLista.Count);
                lResultado.Add(lLista[lintPos]);
                lLista.RemoveAt(lintPos);
            }

            return lResultado;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use the code just do:

```
var randomizeQuery = Query.Randomize();
```

So simple! Thank you lolo_house.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
    var randomizer = new Random();
    var results = from en in context.MyEntity
                  where en.type == myTypeVar
                  let rand = randomizer.Next()
                  orderby rand
                  select en;
```

Comment: I get a similar error to the Guid method in my edit:  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Next()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression..

Comment: The AsEnumerable operator posted on Jon's answer should solve the issue.

Comment: The following code works on my environment: 
var randomizer = new Random(); 
var result = context.MyEntity .Where(en => en.type == myTypeVar) .AsEnumerable() .OrderBy(en => randomizer.Next());

Comment: yes, it seems to work that way round, but not in the from en in context... format.

Answer (score 0):

Toro's answer is the one I would use, but rather like this:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Randomize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
  var list = source.ToList();
  var newList = new List<T>();

  while (source.Count > 0)
  {
     //choose random one and MOVE it from list to newList
  }

  return newList;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to create two lists - you can just swap elements in the list in a shuffle style way. This needs to be done with a bit of care, but it's better (IMO) than creating another copy for no reason.

Comment: You can, but it would make code less readable. IMHO this way is better, because it's more clear. Remember that we operate mainly on references, not values so there isn't much memory cost except for the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice way of doing this (mainly for people Googling).

You can also add .Take(n) on the end to only retrieve a set number.

```
model.CreateQuery<MyEntity>(   
    @"select value source.entity  
      from (select entity, SqlServer.NewID() as rand  
            from Products as entity 
            where entity.type == myTypeVar) as source  
            order by source.rand");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better not to add properties to the class. Better to use the position:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Randomize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> pCol)
    {
        List<T> lResultado = new List<T>();
        List<T> lLista = pCol.ToList();
        Random lRandom = new Random();
        int lintPos = 0;

        while (lLista.Count > 0)
        {
            lintPos = lRandom.Next(lLista.Count);
            lResultado.Add(lLista[lintPos]);
            lLista.RemoveAt(lintPos);
        }

        return lResultado;
    }
```

And the call will (as toList() or toArray()):

var result =  IEnumerable.Where(..).Randomize();

Answer (score 0):

*(cross-posting from [EF Code First: How to get random rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781893/ef-code-first-how-to-get-random-rows/17113105#17113105))*

Comparing two options:

---

### Skip(random number of rows)

#### Method

```
private T getRandomEntity<T>(IGenericRepository<T> repo) where T : EntityWithPk<Guid> {
    var skip = (int)(rand.NextDouble() * repo.Items.Count());
    return repo.Items.OrderBy(o => o.ID).Skip(skip).Take(1).First();
}
```

- Takes 2 queries

#### Generated SQL

```
SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM   (SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM   [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]) AS [GroupBy1];

SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[ID]            AS [ID],
               [Extent1].[Name]          AS [Name],
               [Extent1].[Age]           AS [Age],
               [Extent1].[FavoriteColor] AS [FavoriteColor]
FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[ID]                                  AS [ID],
               [Extent1].[Name]                                AS [Name],
               [Extent1].[Age]                                 AS [Age],
               [Extent1].[FavoriteColor]                       AS [FavoriteColor],
               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Extent1].[ID] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM   [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]) AS [Extent1]
WHERE  [Extent1].[row_number] > 15
ORDER  BY [Extent1].[ID] ASC;
```

---

### Guid

#### Method

```
private T getRandomEntityInPlace<T>(IGenericRepository<T> repo) {
    return repo.Items.OrderBy(o => Guid.NewGuid()).First();
}
```

#### Generated SQL

```
SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[ID]            AS [ID],
               [Project1].[Name]          AS [Name],
               [Project1].[Age]           AS [Age],
               [Project1].[FavoriteColor] AS [FavoriteColor]
FROM   (SELECT NEWID()                   AS [C1],
               [Extent1].[ID]            AS [ID],
               [Extent1].[Name]          AS [Name],
               [Extent1].[Age]           AS [Age],
               [Extent1].[FavoriteColor] AS [FavoriteColor]
        FROM   [dbo].[People] AS [Extent1]) AS [Project1]
ORDER  BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

So in newer EF, you can again see that `NewGuid` is translated into SQL (as confirmed by @DrewNoakes https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120132/1037948).  Even though both are "in-sql" methods, I'm guessing the Guid version is faster?  If you didn't have to sort them in order to skip, and you could reasonably guess the amount to skip, then maybe the Skip method would be better.

Answer (score -1):

Theoretically speaking (I haven't actually tried it yet), the following should do the trick :

Add a partial class to your context class :

```
public partial class MyDataContext{

        [Function(Name = "NEWID", IsComposable = true)] 
        public Guid Random()
        { 
            // you can put anything you want here, it makes no difference 
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
}
```

implementation :

```
from t in context.MyTable
orderby  context.Random()
select t;
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but I can't find a reference for `FunctionAttribute`. Do you mean `EdmFunction` or maybe `DbFunction` instead?

Answer (score -1):

With Entity Framework Core 6+ there's a new function: `EF.Functions.Random()`

```
context.MyEntities
.Where(en => en.type == myTypeVar)
.OrderBy(en => EF.Functions.Random());
```

or

```
from en in context.MyEntities
where en.type == myTypeVar
orderby EF.Functions.Random()
select en;
```

**EDIT**

The advantage of this approach is it uses the internal function of the database engine and one single query. Finally Microsoft implemented it for SQL Server, SQLite, and Azure Cosmos DB. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#effunctionsrandom) and [here[2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/16141#issuecomment-666641607)

Moreover it has the additional advantage to allow you to take a random subset of `MyEntities` by using `Take(n)` at the end of the query.

Comment: You clearly didn't test this. Please do and see why this doen't fit the bill.

Comment: Why you say that? I tested and they work perfectly with EF Core for SQL Server, SQLite, and Azure Cosmos DB. See  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#effunctionsrandom

Comment: On one of your repeated answers it was explained why it doesn't work as expected and yet you decide to leave your answers here.