# Randomize entity framework query results

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Good afternoon,

I have a listview filled using linqdatasource + entity framework iqueryable query.

The query uses a take (top on t-sql) like this:

```
context.Categories().OrderBy(c=>c.Name).Take(20);
```

So it brings me the 20 records I want ordered by name.

Now I want to show those 20 records on a random order. Whats the best approach acomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this turned out to be very simple using extension methods, ordering by name first, then calling Take (top on T-sql) and randomizing later

```
        context.Categories().OrderByName().Take(20).OrderByRandom();


        public static IQueryable<Category> OrderByName(this IQueryable<Category> query)
        {
                return from c in query
                        orderby c.Name
                        select c;
        }



        public static IQueryable<T> OrderByRandom<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
        {
                return (from q in query
                        orderby Guid.NewGuid()
                        select q);
        }
```

Comment: this may work using pure lambda expression without extension methods but I haven't tested it

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working. Are the try/catches needed? If all they do is throw the exception, isn't that the default behavior without them?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the answer in this post is what you need:

[Linq to Entities, random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order)

EDIT:

Get your top 20 records first. Then with the top 20 items you've already fetched, randomize them all in C#, not involving the database at all:

```
var yourRecords = context.Categories().OrderBy(c=>c.Name).Take(20); // I believe .Take() triggers the actual database call
yourRecords = yourRecords.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()); // then randomize the items now that they are in C# memory
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but is not what I need, because it would retrieve me 20 random records from whole data base table and I want to get 20 top records from data base and then show that 20 records on random order

Comment: that's a good and logical answer, it just leaves my linqdatasource out of the scenario. Do you think it can be done on DB?, like if you make this on TSQL

select * from
(select top 20 * from Categories order by Name) as Subquery
order by NewGuid

Comment: Yep, that's definitely possible, too. ORDER BY NEWID() is the T-SQL for it: http://www.codekeep.net/snippets/1687fcea-5f5b-4c6d-b9d3-bd049667d2e1.aspx I assume you could wrap your original query, and then order by newid() in your outer query.

Comment: Hi (sorry for the delay), I've solved it (linq to entities) using an extension method, please see my answer and thank you