# How can I extract 3 random values from an array?

Tags: c#

I build my MyObject array with :

```
    MyObject[] myObject = (from MyObject varObj in MyObjects
                           select varObj).ToArray();
```

and now, I'd like to extract 3 random MyObject from this array! How can I do it on C#?

Of course, if array lenght is <3 I need to extract all objects!

Comment: Two questions: 1) when you say extract do you really mean you want it removed from the array, or just get the value (but also keep in the original array).  2) I'm assuming you don't want to get the same value twice.

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087/select-a-random-n-elements-from-listt-in-c

Comment: Do you want your selection as part of the Linq query?

Comment: 1) It doesnt matter; 2) yeah, 3 the different values, not twice!

Comment: I'd check out the answer @Wolfwyrd noted then, same except Array instead of List but otherwise works just as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        MyObject[] myObject = ...;
        int upper = 1;
        if (myObject.Length > 1)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            upper = Math.Min(3, myObject.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < upper; i++)
            {
                int randInd = r.Next(i, myObject.Length);
                MyObject temp = myObject[i];
                myObject[i] = myObject[randInd];
                myObject[randInd] = temp;
            }
        }
```

now take elements of the array from 0 to `upper`.

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution I'd prefeer :=) Thanks dude

Comment: @markzzz I guarantee that my solution is best in terms of performance (`O(3)`) and in terms of memory (`O(1)`) among others. The problem is that solution that has most votes has dreadful performance and a lot of waste of memory.

Comment: Good in principle, but shouldn't that be `int randInd = r.Next(i, myObject.Length);` otherwise the last element is never going to be included in the shuffle.

Comment: And also worth mentioning that this will mutate the original array as opposed to just returning *n* random elements and leaving the original array alone.

Comment: @LukeH it is mentioned in last sentence. `r.Next(i, myObject.Length);` is **ex** clusive so last element can be picked.

Comment: @Andrey: Actually, I just noticed that you're using `r.Next(i, myObject.Length - i)`, which is completely broken. (I originally misread it as `-1`, not `-i`.) If you want an unbiased shuffle then you need `r.Next(i, myObject.Length)`.

Comment: @LukeH oh, you are completely correct. I confused `.Next` with `string.Substring` where second param is count, not upper limit.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this via Linq:

1. **Retrieve the items in random order** (see [Jon Skeet's answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order))
2. Select Top(3) of the resulting list using the **Take** operator

As an example, select 3 processes at random:

```
var ps = (from p in Process.GetProcesses() orderby Guid.NewGuid() select p).Take(3);
```

You can also use random.Next() instead of Guids (since strictly speaking, as pointed out by LukeH, Guids are unique, but not random).

Comment: This is really elengant! How can I get top(3) on linq? Don't know how to do the random order on linq...

Comment: Yeah, I am still learning to think in terms of sets (like the SQL guys do it) rather than procedural processing.

Comment: This solution is elegant in terms of code but not in terms of performance. Problem is that it will sort whole array, which is not necessary at all.

Comment: Make sure you read Jon Skeet's answer to the linked SO question. Basically, order by Guid.NewGuid() as part of your Linq query.

Comment: @Philipp Schmid it is such a waste of performance to generate Guids for each element just to shuffle them.

Comment: Agreed. But sometimes the simplicity (and correctness) of a solution is more important than a few milliseconds of performance gains.

Comment: @Philipp: That's true, but ordering by GUIDs is *not* correct. GUIDs are guaranteed to be *unique*, not random.

Comment: @Philipp Schmid sometimes yes, sometimes not. If you run this on server lots of times then you will start bothering about milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

using `Random` class of `C#` you can get random `int` which are less than a particular number which in your case will be the size of `myObject`

I am not sure you want unique or they can duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
Random r = new Random();
int item1 = r.Next(0, myObject.Length);
int item2 = r.Next(0, myObject.Length);
int item3 = r.Next(0, myObject.Length);

var result1 = myObject[item1];
var result2 = myObject[item2];
var result3 = myObject[item3];
```

No Linq or anything, but it gets the job done.

Comment: This could be a problem. If item1 and item2 are the same? I'll extract only 2 items...

Comment: Yea, it doesn't actually check to make sure you're not getting 3 copies of the same item (ie. you only have 1 item in the array).  I guess I figured you could handle that.  I was just trying to demonstrate the use of the `Random` class to get your random indexes.

Comment: Make a function that returns a random number, with the numbers you don't want passed in as an integer array?

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
 var random = new Random();
 var objs = new Object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
 var result = objs.OrderBy(o => random.Next(Int32.MaxValue)).Take(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little bit more creative.

```
 var list = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4, 1, 2, 3, 44, 5, 6 };
 Random random = new Random();
 var results = list.OrderBy(i => random.Next()).Take(3);
```

Output:

```
results: {int[3]}
[0]: 3
[1]: 2
[2]: 5
```