# Entity Framework Include OrderBy random generates duplicate data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, random, sql-order-by

When I retrieve a list of items from a database including some children (via .Include), and order the randomly, EF gives me an unexpected result.. I creates/clones addition items..

To explain myself better, I've created a small and simple EF CodeFirst project to reproduce the problem.
First i shall give you the code for this project.

### The project

Create a basic MVC3 project and add the EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact package via Nuget.
That adds the latest versions of the following packages:

- EntityFramework v4.3.0
- SqlServerCompact v4.0.8482.1
- EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact v4.1.8482.2
- WebActivator v1.5

**The Models and DbContext**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace RandomWithInclude.Models
{
    public class PeopleContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AdressLine { get; set; }

        public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The DB Setup and Seed data: EF.SqlServerCompact.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using RandomWithInclude.Models;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(RandomWithInclude.App_Start.EF), "Start")]

namespace RandomWithInclude.App_Start
{
    public static class EF
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
            Database.SetInitializer(new DbInitializer());
        }
    }
    public class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<PeopleContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(PeopleContext context)
        {
            var address1 = new Address {AdressLine = "Street 1, City 1"};
            var address2 = new Address {AdressLine = "Street 2, City 2"};
            var address3 = new Address {AdressLine = "Street 3, City 3"};
            var address4 = new Address {AdressLine = "Street 4, City 4"};
            var address5 = new Address {AdressLine = "Street 5, City 5"};
            context.Addresses.Add(address1);
            context.Addresses.Add(address2);
            context.Addresses.Add(address3);
            context.Addresses.Add(address4);
            context.Addresses.Add(address5);
            var person1 = new Person {Name = "Person 1", Addresses = new List<Address> {address1, address2}};
            var person2 = new Person {Name = "Person 2", Addresses = new List<Address> {address3}};
            var person3 = new Person {Name = "Person 3", Addresses = new List<Address> {address4, address5}};
            context.Persons.Add(person1);
            context.Persons.Add(person2);
            context.Persons.Add(person3);
        }
    }
}
```

**The controller: HomeController.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using RandomWithInclude.Models;

namespace RandomWithInclude.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var db = new PeopleContext();
            var persons = db.Persons
                                .Include(p => p.Addresses)
                                .OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid());

            return View(persons.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

**The View: Index.cshtml**

```cs
@using RandomWithInclude.Models
@model IList<Person>

<ul>
    @foreach (var person in Model)
    {
        <li>
            @person.Name
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

this should be all, and you application should compile :)

---

### The problem

As you can see, we have 2 straightforward models (Person and Address) and Person can have multiple Addresses.
We seed the generated database **3 persons** and 5 addresses.
If we get all the persons from the database, including the addresses and randomize the results and just print out the names of those persons, **that's where it all goes wrong.**

As a result, i sometimes get 4 persons, sometimes 5 and sometimes 3, and i expect 3. Always.
e.g.:

- Person 1
- Person 3
- Person 1
- Person 3
- Person 2

So.. it's copying/cloning data! And that's not cool..
It just seems that EF looses track of what addresses are a child of which person..

The generated SQL query is this:

```sql
SELECT 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[ID1] AS [ID1], 
    [Project1].[AdressLine] AS [AdressLine], 
    [Project1].[Person_ID] AS [Person_ID]
FROM ( SELECT 
    NEWID() AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
    [Extent2].[AdressLine] AS [AdressLine], 
    [Extent2].[Person_ID] AS [Person_ID], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM  [People] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Addresses] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[Person_ID]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC, [Project1].[ID] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC
```

### Workarounds

1. If i remove the `.Include(p =>p.Addresses)` from the query, everything goes fine. but of course the addresses aren't loaded and accessing that collection will make a new call to the database every time.
2. I can first get the data from the database and randomize later by just adding a .ToList() before the .OrderBy.. like this: `var persons = db.Persons.Include(p => p.Addresses).ToList().OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid());`

Does anybody have any idea of why it is happening like this?
Might this be a bug in the SQL generation?

Comment: "Might this be a bug in the SQL generation" - have you tried executing the both queries (working/non working) and see if they differ in the result? Anyways. I think this is just another bug you have found in the framework. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx and "Projecting to an Anonymous Type" this somehow smells related. There's something fishy that needs to be killed in this framework.

Comment: @stefan: yes i've tried that, and of course returns a different result, which indeed points to a sql generation bug.. But i don't think it is listed there already..

Comment: The problem occurs by the way also with EF 4.1 on SQL Server (tested on 2008 R2), not only with SQLCompact. I think, @np-hard's answer is correct that the problem is in EF's object materialization, not in the generated SQL. If `OrderBy` is not on a property of the parent entity, nonsense happens.

Answer (score 12):

As one can sort it out by reading [AakashM answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8168872/1178314) and [Nicolae Dascalu answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8176375/1178314), it strongly seems Linq `OrderBy` requires a stable ranking function, which `NewID/Guid.NewGuid` is not.

So we have to use another random generator that would be stable inside a single query.

To achieve this, before each querying, use a .Net Random generator to get a random number. Then combine this random number with a unique property of the entity to get randomly sorted. And to 'randomize' a bit the result, `checksum` it. (`checksum` is a SQL Server function that compute a hash; original idea founded on [this blog](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/perils-t-sql-randomization).)

Assuming `Person` `Id` is an `int`, you could write your query this way :

```
// Random instances should be stored and reused, not instanciated at each usage.
// But beware, it is not thread safe. If you want to share it between threads, you
// would have to use locks, see its documentation.
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.
// But using locks is a bad idea for scalability, especially in a Web context.
var randomGenerator = new Random();
// ...

var rnd = randomGenerator.NextDouble();
var persons = db.Persons
    .Include(p => p.Addresses)
    .OrderBy(p => SqlFunctions.Checksum(p.Id * rnd));
```

Like the `NewGuid` hack, this is very probably not a good random generator with a good distribution and so on. But it does not cause entities to get duplicated in results.

**Beware:**
If your query ordering does not guarantees uniqueness of your entities ranking, you must complement it for guarantying it. By example, if you use a non-unique property of your entities for the checksum call, then add something like `.ThenBy(p => p.Id)` after the `OrderBy`.
If your ranking is not unique for your queried root entity, its included children may get mixed with children of other entities having the same ranking. And then the bug will stay here.

**Note:**
I would prefer use `.Next()` method to get an `int` then combine it through a xor (`^`) to an entity `int` unique property, rather than using a `double` and multiply it. But [`SqlFunctions.Checksum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.checksum) unfortunately does not provide an overload for `int` data type, though the SQL server function is supposed to support it. You may use a cast to overcome this, but for keeping it simple I finally had chosen to go with the multiply.

Comment: Nice solution! But what about performance? It doesn't seem lightweight at all!

Comment: On my current data volume and requests load, this does not have noticeable impact for user. But my current data volume is light : less than 5 000 matching rows to sort. (And due to the app nature, it will probably not go higher than 50 000.)  
Anyway, I have already a fallback in place: I use the same technic in a sql job for regularly recomputing an indexed `RandomRank` column on target tables, for other cases where I need a "static" random ordering across requests. So if the perf of dynamic goes wrong, I may negotiate with business to use the static one everywhere instead.

Comment: And by the way, this `CheckSum` sort does not look to me heavier than the `NewGuid` sort: both causes the server to have no index on which to perform the sort; `NewID` computations are probably not really lighter than a multiplication followed by a checksum.

Comment: Where does SqlFunctions come from? How can I do this in .NET Core?

Comment: It does not seems available with .Net Core. See the link I have added to reference in my last paragraph.

Answer (score 8):

tl;dr: There's a leaky abstraction here. To us, `Include` is a simple instruction to stick a *collection* of things onto each single returned `Person` row. But EF's implementation of `Include` is done by returning a whole row for each `Person-Address` combo, and reassembling at the client. Ordering by a volatile value causes those rows to become shuffled, breaking apart the `Person` groups that EF is relying on.

---

When we have a look at `ToTraceString()` for this LINQ:

```
 var people = c.People.Include("Addresses");
 // Note: no OrderBy in sight!
```

we see

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project1].[Data] AS [Data], 
[Project1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
    [Extent2].[Data] AS [Data], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM  [Person] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PersonId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

So we get `n` rows for each `A`, plus `1` row for each `P` without any `A`s.

Adding an `OrderBy` clause, however, puts the thing-to-order-by at the **start** of the ordered columns:

```
var people = c.People.Include("Addresses").OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid());
```

gives

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
[Project1].[Data] AS [Data], 
[Project1].[PersonId] AS [PersonId]
FROM ( SELECT 
    NEWID() AS [C1], 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[PersonId] AS [PersonId], 
    [Extent2].[Data] AS [Data], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C2]
    FROM  [Person] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [Address] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PersonId]
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC, [Project1].[Id] ASC, [Project1].[C2] ASC
```

So in your case, where the ordered-by-thing is not a property of a `P`, but is instead volatile, and therefore can be **different for different `P-A` records of the *same* `P`**, the whole thing falls apart.

---

I'm not sure where on the `working-as-intended ~~~ cast-iron bug` continuum this behaviour falls. But at least now we know about it.

Comment: See [Nicolae answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8176375/1178314), it really could be a "work as intended case" and even "expected". So long for the `NewGuid` random sort hack, it simply looks like broken.

Answer (score 5):

I dont think there is an issue in query generation, but there is definately an issue when EF tries to convert rows into object.

It looks like there is an inherent assumption here that data for the same person in a joined statement will be returned grouped together order by or not.

for example the result of a joined query will always be

```
P.Id P.Name  A.Id A.StreetLine
1    Person 1 10    --- 
1    Person 1 11
2    Person 2 12
3    Person 3 13
3    Person 3 14
```

even if you order by some other column, same person would always appear one after the other.

this assumption is mostly true for any joined query.

But there is a deeper issue here i think. OrderBy is for when you want data in certain order ( as opposite to random), so that assumption does seem reasonable.

i think you should really get data out and then randomize it according to some other means in your code

Comment: "inherent assumption": I agree and would guess the same. Object materialization returns wrong result in case of random sorting and a possible fix would require that EF groups the returned data which would make materialization of eagerly loaded data more expensive. Sorting in memory is also possibly cheaper because it only sorts the parent entities and not the two joined (parent,child) tables as the database would do.

Comment: "OrderBy is for when you want data in certain order ( as opposite to random)" How is random order NOT a certain order? Also "random" in computer science is just a specific algorithm so its just order by a unique-for-the-query sequence.

Comment: well in my defense, random as an adjective does mean 'lacking any definate plan or prearranged order' :-)

Answer (score 2):

From theory:
To sort a list of items, the compare function should be stable relative to items; this means that for any 2 items x, y the result of x< y should be the same as many time is queried(called).

I think the issue is related to misunderstanding of specification(documentation) of [OrderBy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx):
 *keySelector - A function to extract a key from an element*.

[EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) didn't mention explicitly if the provided function should return the same value for same object as many times is called (in your case returns different/random values), but I think the "key" term that they used in documentation implicitly suggested this.

Comment: This [blog post](https://lostechies.com/patricklioi/2013/09/14/shufflin-aint-sortin/) further confirm that using unstable compare function leads to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a query path to define the query results, (use **Include**), the query path is only valid on the returned instance of ObjectQuery. Other instances of ObjectQuery and the object context itself are not affected. This functionality lets you chain multiple "Includes" for eager loading.

Therefor, Your statement translates into

```
from person in db.Persons.Include(p => p.Addresses).OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())
select person
```

instead of what you intended.

```
from person in db.Persons.Include(p => p.Addresses)
select person
.OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())
```

Hence your second workaround works fine :)

Reference: Loading Related Objects While Querying A Conceptual Model in Entity
    Framework - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx

Comment: Hey @Sai, thanks for you reaction, but  you query is syntactically incorrect. i changed it to: `(from person in db.Persons.Include(p => p.Addresses) select person).OrderBy(p => Guid.NewGuid())`, but that just generates the same SQL and keeps the issue.. So this is not the answer. just my query written differently :)

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this problem, and solved it by adding a Randomizer Guid property to the main class I was fetching. I then set the column's default value to NEWID() like this (using EF Core 2)

```
builder.Entity<MainClass>()
    .Property(m => m.Randomizer)
    .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
```

When fetching, it gets a bit more complicated. I created two random integers to function as my order-by indexes, then ran the query like this

```
var rand = new Random();
var randomIndex1 = rand.Next(0, 31);
var randomIndex2 = rand.Next(0, 31);
var taskSet = await DbContext.MainClasses
    .Include(m => m.SubClass1)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.SubClass2)
    .OrderBy(m => m.Randomizer.ToString().Replace("-", "")[randomIndex1])
        .ThenBy(m => m.Randomizer.ToString().Replace("-", "")[randomIndex2])
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This seems to be working well enough, and should provide enough entropy for even a large dataset to be fairly randomized.