# Entity framework OrderBy will result in multiple OrderBy statments beign executed at the database level

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code inside my action method inside my asp.net mvc:-

```
var vm = repository.ITVMsCore()
                   .OrderBy(a => a.Technology.PartialTag)
                   .ToPagedList(page, pagesize);
```

which will call the following repository method:-

```
 public IQueryable<ITVirtualMachine> ITVMsCore()
 {
     return IT.ITVirtualMachines
              .Include(a2 => a2.Technology.TechnologyType)
              .Include(a6 => a6.Technology.TechnologyIPs)
              .Include(a10 => a10.ITServer.Technology)
              .Include(a11 => a11.ITServer.ITRack.Technology);
```

when I call the action method, the Sql profiler have generated the following long query:-

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project2].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
[Project2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
[Project2].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID], 
[Project2].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID], 
[Project2].[TechnologyID1] AS [TechnologyID1], 
[Project2].[ITRackID1] AS [ITRackID1], 
[Project2].[ITServerID1] AS [ITServerID1], 
[Project2].[ITRackID2] AS [ITRackID2], 
[Project2].[ITServerID2] AS [ITServerID2], 
[Project2].[TechnologyID3] AS [TechnologyID2], 
[Project2].[ITRackID3] AS [ITRackID3], 
[Project2].[ITServerID3] AS [ITServerID3], 
[Project2].[ITRackID4] AS [ITRackID4], 
[Project2].[ITVirtualMachineID1] AS [ITVirtualMachineID1], 
[Project2].[ITServerID5] AS [ITServerID4], 
[Project2].[ServerID] AS [ServerID], 
[Project2].[ITServerID4] AS [ITServerID5], 
[Project2].[ITRackID5] AS [ITRackID5], 
[Project2].[ITServerID6] AS [ITServerID6], 
[Project2].[ITVirtualMachineID2] AS [ITVirtualMachineID2], 
[Project2].[ITRackID6] AS [ITRackID6], 
[Project2].[RoleID] AS [RoleID], 
[Project2].[BackUpStatusID] AS [BackUpStatusID], 
[Project2].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
[Project2].[MonitoreID] AS [MonitoreID], 
[Project2].[TotalStorage] AS [TotalStorage], 
[Project2].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
[Project2].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
[Project2].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
[Project2].[TechnologyID2] AS [TechnologyID3], 
[Project2].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
[Project2].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
[Project2].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], 
[Project2].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
[Project2].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
[Project2].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
[Project2].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
[Project2].[PartialTag1] AS [PartialTag], 
[Project2].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], 
[Project2].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project2].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], 
[Project2].[ServerModelID] AS [ServerModelID], 
[Project2].[ILOIP] AS [ILOIP], 
[Project2].[RackID] AS [RackID], 
[Project2].[StatusID1] AS [StatusID1], 
[Project2].[BackUpStatusID1] AS [BackUpStatusID1], 
[Project2].[RoleID1] AS [RoleID1], 
[Project2].[OperatingSystemID] AS [OperatingSystemID], 
[Project2].[VirtualCenterID] AS [VirtualCenterID], 
[Project2].[Comment1] AS [Comment1], 
[Project2].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], 
[Project2].[IT360SiteID1] AS [IT360SiteID1], 
[Project2].[TechnologyID4] AS [TechnologyID4], 
[Project2].[Tag1] AS [Tag1], 
[Project2].[IsDeleted1] AS [IsDeleted1], 
[Project2].[timestamp3] AS [timestamp3], 
[Project2].[TypeID1] AS [TypeID1], 
[Project2].[StartDate1] AS [StartDate1], 
[Project2].[IT360ID1] AS [IT360ID1], 
[Project2].[IsCompleted1] AS [IsCompleted1], 
[Project2].[PartialTag2] AS [PartialTag1], 
[Project2].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
[Project2].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
[Project2].[timestamp4] AS [timestamp4], 
[Project2].[IT360SiteID2] AS [IT360SiteID2], 
[Project2].[TechnologyID5] AS [TechnologyID5], 
[Project2].[Tag2] AS [Tag2], 
[Project2].[IsDeleted2] AS [IsDeleted2], 
[Project2].[timestamp5] AS [timestamp5], 
[Project2].[TypeID2] AS [TypeID2], 
[Project2].[StartDate2] AS [StartDate2], 
[Project2].[IT360ID2] AS [IT360ID2], 
[Project2].[IsCompleted2] AS [IsCompleted2], 
[Project2].[PartialTag3] AS [PartialTag2], 
[Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
[Project2].[TechnologyID6] AS [TechnologyID6], 
[Project2].[IPAddress] AS [IPAddress], 
[Project2].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Project2].[MACAddress] AS [MACAddress], 
[Project2].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Limit1].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID], 
    [Limit1].[ServerID] AS [ServerID], 
    [Limit1].[RoleID] AS [RoleID], 
    [Limit1].[BackUpStatusID] AS [BackUpStatusID], 
    [Limit1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
    [Limit1].[MonitoreID] AS [MonitoreID], 
    [Limit1].[TotalStorage] AS [TotalStorage], 
    [Limit1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
    [Limit1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
    [Limit1].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
    [Limit1].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
    [Limit1].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
    [Limit1].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID], 
    [Limit1].[TechnologyID1] AS [TechnologyID1], 
    [Limit1].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], 
    [Limit1].[ITRackID1] AS [ITRackID1], 
    [Limit1].[ITServerID1] AS [ITServerID1], 
    [Limit1].[TechnologyID2] AS [TechnologyID2], 
    [Limit1].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
    [Limit1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
    [Limit1].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], 
    [Limit1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
    [Limit1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
    [Limit1].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
    [Limit1].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
    [Limit1].[PartialTag1] AS [PartialTag1], 
    [Limit1].[ITRackID2] AS [ITRackID2], 
    [Limit1].[ITServerID2] AS [ITServerID2], 
    [Limit1].[TechnologyID3] AS [TechnologyID3], 
    [Limit1].[ITRackID3] AS [ITRackID3], 
    [Limit1].[ITServerID3] AS [ITServerID3], 
    [Limit1].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], 
    [Limit1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Limit1].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], 
    [Limit1].[ITServerID4] AS [ITServerID4], 
    [Limit1].[ServerModelID] AS [ServerModelID], 
    [Limit1].[ILOIP] AS [ILOIP], 
    [Limit1].[RackID] AS [RackID], 
    [Limit1].[StatusID1] AS [StatusID1], 
    [Limit1].[BackUpStatusID1] AS [BackUpStatusID1], 
    [Limit1].[RoleID1] AS [RoleID1], 
    [Limit1].[OperatingSystemID] AS [OperatingSystemID], 
    [Limit1].[VirtualCenterID] AS [VirtualCenterID], 
    [Limit1].[Comment1] AS [Comment1], 
    [Limit1].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], 
    [Limit1].[IT360SiteID1] AS [IT360SiteID1], 
    [Limit1].[TechnologyID4] AS [TechnologyID4], 
    [Limit1].[Tag1] AS [Tag1], 
    [Limit1].[IsDeleted1] AS [IsDeleted1], 
    [Limit1].[timestamp3] AS [timestamp3], 
    [Limit1].[TypeID1] AS [TypeID1], 
    [Limit1].[StartDate1] AS [StartDate1], 
    [Limit1].[IT360ID1] AS [IT360ID1], 
    [Limit1].[IsCompleted1] AS [IsCompleted1], 
    [Limit1].[PartialTag2] AS [PartialTag2], 
    [Limit1].[ITRackID4] AS [ITRackID4], 
    [Limit1].[ITServerID5] AS [ITServerID5], 
    [Limit1].[ITVirtualMachineID1] AS [ITVirtualMachineID1], 
    [Limit1].[ITRackID5] AS [ITRackID5], 
    [Limit1].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
    [Limit1].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
    [Limit1].[timestamp4] AS [timestamp4], 
    [Limit1].[IT360SiteID2] AS [IT360SiteID2], 
    [Limit1].[TechnologyID5] AS [TechnologyID5], 
    [Limit1].[Tag2] AS [Tag2], 
    [Limit1].[IsDeleted2] AS [IsDeleted2], 
    [Limit1].[timestamp5] AS [timestamp5], 
    [Limit1].[TypeID2] AS [TypeID2], 
    [Limit1].[StartDate2] AS [StartDate2], 
    [Limit1].[IT360ID2] AS [IT360ID2], 
    [Limit1].[IsCompleted2] AS [IsCompleted2], 
    [Limit1].[PartialTag3] AS [PartialTag3], 
    [Limit1].[ITRackID6] AS [ITRackID6], 
    [Limit1].[ITServerID6] AS [ITServerID6], 
    [Limit1].[ITVirtualMachineID2] AS [ITVirtualMachineID2], 
    [Join24].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID6], 
    [Join24].[IPAddress] AS [IPAddress], 
    [Join24].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Join24].[MACAddress] AS [MACAddress], 
    [Join24].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], 
    CASE WHEN ([Join24].[ID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
    FROM   (SELECT TOP (15) [Project1].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID], [Project1].[ServerID] AS [ServerID], [Project1].[RoleID] AS [RoleID], [Project1].[BackUpStatusID] AS [BackUpStatusID], [Project1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], [Project1].[MonitoreID] AS [MonitoreID], [Project1].[TotalStorage] AS [TotalStorage], [Project1].[Comment] AS [Comment], [Project1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project1].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project1].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project1].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project1].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID], [Project1].[TechnologyID1] AS [TechnologyID1], [Project1].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project1].[ITRackID1] AS [ITRackID1], [Project1].[ITServerID1] AS [ITServerID1], [Project1].[TechnologyID2] AS [TechnologyID2], [Project1].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project1].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project1].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project1].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project1].[PartialTag1] AS [PartialTag1], [Project1].[ITRackID2] AS [ITRackID2], [Project1].[ITServerID2] AS [ITServerID2], [Project1].[TechnologyID3] AS [TechnologyID3], [Project1].[ITRackID3] AS [ITRackID3], [Project1].[ITServerID3] AS [ITServerID3], [Project1].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], [Project1].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], [Project1].[ITServerID4] AS [ITServerID4], [Project1].[ServerModelID] AS [ServerModelID], [Project1].[ILOIP] AS [ILOIP], [Project1].[RackID] AS [RackID], [Project1].[StatusID1] AS [StatusID1], [Project1].[BackUpStatusID1] AS [BackUpStatusID1], [Project1].[RoleID1] AS [RoleID1], [Project1].[OperatingSystemID] AS [OperatingSystemID], [Project1].[VirtualCenterID] AS [VirtualCenterID], [Project1].[Comment1] AS [Comment1], [Project1].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project1].[IT360SiteID1] AS [IT360SiteID1], [Project1].[TechnologyID4] AS [TechnologyID4], [Project1].[Tag1] AS [Tag1], [Project1].[IsDeleted1] AS [IsDeleted1], [Project1].[timestamp3] AS [timestamp3], [Project1].[TypeID1] AS [TypeID1], [Project1].[StartDate1] AS [StartDate1], [Project1].[IT360ID1] AS [IT360ID1], [Project1].[IsCompleted1] AS [IsCompleted1], [Project1].[PartialTag2] AS [PartialTag2], [Project1].[ITRackID4] AS [ITRackID4], [Project1].[ITServerID5] AS [ITServerID5], [Project1].[ITVirtualMachineID1] AS [ITVirtualMachineID1], [Project1].[ITRackID5] AS [ITRackID5], [Project1].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project1].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project1].[timestamp4] AS [timestamp4], [Project1].[IT360SiteID2] AS [IT360SiteID2], [Project1].[TechnologyID5] AS [TechnologyID5], [Project1].[Tag2] AS [Tag2], [Project1].[IsDeleted2] AS [IsDeleted2], [Project1].[timestamp5] AS [timestamp5], [Project1].[TypeID2] AS [TypeID2], [Project1].[StartDate2] AS [StartDate2], [Project1].[IT360ID2] AS [IT360ID2], [Project1].[IsCompleted2] AS [IsCompleted2], [Project1].[PartialTag3] AS [PartialTag3], [Project1].[ITRackID6] AS [ITRackID6], [Project1].[ITServerID6] AS [ITServerID6], [Project1].[ITVirtualMachineID2] AS [ITVirtualMachineID2]
        FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID], [Project1].[ServerID] AS [ServerID], [Project1].[RoleID] AS [RoleID], [Project1].[BackUpStatusID] AS [BackUpStatusID], [Project1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], [Project1].[MonitoreID] AS [MonitoreID], [Project1].[TotalStorage] AS [TotalStorage], [Project1].[Comment] AS [Comment], [Project1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], [Project1].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], [Project1].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Project1].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Project1].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID], [Project1].[TechnologyID1] AS [TechnologyID1], [Project1].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Project1].[ITRackID1] AS [ITRackID1], [Project1].[ITServerID1] AS [ITServerID1], [Project1].[TechnologyID2] AS [TechnologyID2], [Project1].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Project1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Project1].[timestamp1] AS [timestamp1], [Project1].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Project1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Project1].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Project1].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Project1].[PartialTag1] AS [PartialTag1], [Project1].[ITRackID2] AS [ITRackID2], [Project1].[ITServerID2] AS [ITServerID2], [Project1].[TechnologyID3] AS [TechnologyID3], [Project1].[ITRackID3] AS [ITRackID3], [Project1].[ITServerID3] AS [ITServerID3], [Project1].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], [Project1].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], [Project1].[ITServerID4] AS [ITServerID4], [Project1].[ServerModelID] AS [ServerModelID], [Project1].[ILOIP] AS [ILOIP], [Project1].[RackID] AS [RackID], [Project1].[StatusID1] AS [StatusID1], [Project1].[BackUpStatusID1] AS [BackUpStatusID1], [Project1].[RoleID1] AS [RoleID1], [Project1].[OperatingSystemID] AS [OperatingSystemID], [Project1].[VirtualCenterID] AS [VirtualCenterID], [Project1].[Comment1] AS [Comment1], [Project1].[timestamp2] AS [timestamp2], [Project1].[IT360SiteID1] AS [IT360SiteID1], [Project1].[TechnologyID4] AS [TechnologyID4], [Project1].[Tag1] AS [Tag1], [Project1].[IsDeleted1] AS [IsDeleted1], [Project1].[timestamp3] AS [timestamp3], [Project1].[TypeID1] AS [TypeID1], [Project1].[StartDate1] AS [StartDate1], [Project1].[IT360ID1] AS [IT360ID1], [Project1].[IsCompleted1] AS [IsCompleted1], [Project1].[PartialTag2] AS [PartialTag2], [Project1].[ITRackID4] AS [ITRackID4], [Project1].[ITServerID5] AS [ITServerID5], [Project1].[ITVirtualMachineID1] AS [ITVirtualMachineID1], [Project1].[ITRackID5] AS [ITRackID5], [Project1].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], [Project1].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], [Project1].[timestamp4] AS [timestamp4], [Project1].[IT360SiteID2] AS [IT360SiteID2], [Project1].[TechnologyID5] AS [TechnologyID5], [Project1].[Tag2] AS [Tag2], [Project1].[IsDeleted2] AS [IsDeleted2], [Project1].[timestamp5] AS [timestamp5], [Project1].[TypeID2] AS [TypeID2], [Project1].[StartDate2] AS [StartDate2], [Project1].[IT360ID2] AS [IT360ID2], [Project1].[IsCompleted2] AS [IsCompleted2], [Project1].[PartialTag3] AS [PartialTag3], [Project1].[ITRackID6] AS [ITRackID6], [Project1].[ITServerID6] AS [ITServerID6], [Project1].[ITVirtualMachineID2] AS [ITVirtualMachineID2], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[PartialTag] ASC) AS [row_number]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID], 
                [Extent1].[ServerID] AS [ServerID], 
                [Extent1].[RoleID] AS [RoleID], 
                [Extent1].[BackUpStatusID] AS [BackUpStatusID], 
                [Extent1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
                [Extent1].[MonitoreID] AS [MonitoreID], 
                [Extent1].[TotalStorage] AS [TotalStorage], 
                [Extent1].[Comment] AS [Comment], 
                [Extent1].[timestamp] AS [timestamp], 
                [Extent1].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID], 
                [Join2].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], 
                [Join2].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], 
                [Join2].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID], 
                [Join5].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID1], 
                [Join5].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], 
                [Join5].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID1], 
                [Join5].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID1], 
                [Join8].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID2], 
                [Join8].[Tag] AS [Tag], 
                [Join8].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], 
                [Join8].[timestamp6] AS [timestamp1], 
                [Join8].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], 
                [Join8].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], 
                [Join8].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], 
                [Join8].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], 
                [Join8].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag1], 
                [Join8].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID2], 
                [Join8].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID2], 
                [Join11].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID3], 
                [Join11].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID3], 
                [Join11].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID3], 
                [Extent14].[AssetTypeID] AS [AssetTypeID], 
                [Extent14].[Name] AS [Name], 
                [Extent14].[IncludedInSearch] AS [IncludedInSearch], 
                [Extent15].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID4], 
                [Extent15].[ServerModelID] AS [ServerModelID], 
                [Extent15].[ILOIP] AS [ILOIP], 
                [Extent15].[RackID] AS [RackID], 
                [Extent15].[StatusID] AS [StatusID1], 
                [Extent15].[BackUpStatusID] AS [BackUpStatusID1], 
                [Extent15].[RoleID] AS [RoleID1], 
                [Extent15].[OperatingSystemID] AS [OperatingSystemID], 
                [Extent15].[VirtualCenterID] AS [VirtualCenterID], 
                [Extent15].[Comment] AS [Comment1], 
                [Extent15].[timestamp] AS [timestamp2], 
                [Extent15].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID1], 
                [Join17].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID4], 
                [Join17].[Tag] AS [Tag1], 
                [Join17].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted1], 
                [Join17].[timestamp7] AS [timestamp3], 
                [Join17].[TypeID] AS [TypeID1], 
                [Join17].[StartDate] AS [StartDate1], 
                [Join17].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID1], 
                [Join17].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted1], 
                [Join17].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag2], 
                [Join17].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID4], 
                [Join17].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID5], 
                [Join17].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID1], 
                [Extent20].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID5], 
                [Extent20].[DataCenterID] AS [DataCenterID], 
                [Extent20].[ZoneID] AS [ZoneID], 
                [Extent20].[timestamp] AS [timestamp4], 
                [Extent20].[IT360SiteID] AS [IT360SiteID2], 
                [Join22].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID5], 
                [Join22].[Tag] AS [Tag2], 
                [Join22].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted2], 
                [Join22].[timestamp8] AS [timestamp5], 
                [Join22].[TypeID] AS [TypeID2], 
                [Join22].[StartDate] AS [StartDate2], 
                [Join22].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID2], 
                [Join22].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted2], 
                [Join22].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag3], 
                [Join22].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID6], 
                [Join22].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID6], 
                [Join22].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID2]
                FROM          [dbo].[ITVirtualMachines] AS [Extent1]
                INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Extent2].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Extent3].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Extent4].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent2]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[TechnologyID] = [Extent3].[ITRackID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent2].[TechnologyID] = [Extent4].[ITServerID] ) AS [Join2] ON [Extent1].[ITVirtualMachineID] = [Join2].[TechnologyID]
                INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent5].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Extent5].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Extent6].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Extent7].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent5]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent5].[TechnologyID] = [Extent6].[ITRackID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent7] ON [Extent5].[TechnologyID] = [Extent7].[ITServerID] ) AS [Join5] ON [Extent1].[ITVirtualMachineID] = [Join5].[TechnologyID]
                INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent8].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Extent8].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Extent8].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent8].[timestamp] AS [timestamp6], [Extent8].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Extent8].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Extent8].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Extent8].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Extent8].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Extent9].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Extent10].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent8]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent8].[TechnologyID] = [Extent9].[ITRackID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent10] ON [Extent8].[TechnologyID] = [Extent10].[ITServerID] ) AS [Join8] ON [Extent1].[ITVirtualMachineID] = [Join8].[TechnologyID]
                INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent11].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Extent11].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Extent12].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Extent13].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent11]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent11].[TechnologyID] = [Extent12].[ITRackID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent13] ON [Extent11].[TechnologyID] = [Extent13].[ITServerID] ) AS [Join11] ON [Extent1].[ITVirtualMachineID] = [Join11].[TechnologyID]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TechnologyTypes] AS [Extent14] ON [Join11].[TypeID] = [Extent14].[AssetTypeID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent1].[ServerID] = [Extent15].[ITServerID]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent16].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Extent16].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Extent16].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent16].[timestamp] AS [timestamp7], [Extent16].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Extent16].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Extent16].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Extent16].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Extent16].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Extent17].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Extent18].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID], [Extent19].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID]
                    FROM    [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent16]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent17] ON [Extent16].[TechnologyID] = [Extent17].[ITRackID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent16].[TechnologyID] = [Extent18].[ITServerID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITVirtualMachines] AS [Extent19] ON [Extent16].[TechnologyID] = [Extent19].[ITVirtualMachineID] ) AS [Join17] ON [Extent1].[ServerID] = [Join17].[ITServerID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent20] ON [Extent15].[RackID] = [Extent20].[ITRackID]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent21].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Extent21].[Tag] AS [Tag], [Extent21].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted], [Extent21].[timestamp] AS [timestamp8], [Extent21].[TypeID] AS [TypeID], [Extent21].[StartDate] AS [StartDate], [Extent21].[IT360ID] AS [IT360ID], [Extent21].[IsCompleted] AS [IsCompleted], [Extent21].[PartialTag] AS [PartialTag], [Extent22].[ITRackID] AS [ITRackID], [Extent23].[ITServerID] AS [ITServerID], [Extent24].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID]
                    FROM    [dbo].[Technology] AS [Extent21]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITRacks] AS [Extent22] ON [Extent21].[TechnologyID] = [Extent22].[ITRackID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITServers] AS [Extent23] ON [Extent21].[TechnologyID] = [Extent23].[ITServerID]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ITVirtualMachines] AS [Extent24] ON [Extent21].[TechnologyID] = [Extent24].[ITVirtualMachineID] ) AS [Join22] ON [Extent20].[ITRackID] = [Join22].[ITRackID]
                WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL) OR (( CAST(LEN(@p__linq__0) AS int)) = 0) OR (( CAST(CHARINDEX(UPPER(@p__linq__1), UPPER([Join2].[Tag])) AS int)) = 1)
            )  AS [Project1]
        )  AS [Project1]
        WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
        ORDER BY [Project1].[PartialTag] ASC ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent25].[TechnologyID] AS [TechnologyID], [Extent25].[IPAddress] AS [IPAddress], [Extent25].[ID] AS [ID], [Extent25].[MACAddress] AS [MACAddress], [Extent25].[IsPrimary] AS [IsPrimary], [Extent26].[ITVirtualMachineID] AS [ITVirtualMachineID]
        FROM  [dbo].[TechnologyIP] AS [Extent25]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[ITVirtualMachines] AS [Extent26] ON [Extent25].[TechnologyID] = [Extent26].[ITVirtualMachineID] ) AS [Join24] ON [Limit1].[ITVirtualMachineID] = [Join24].[ITVirtualMachineID]
)  AS [Project2]
ORDER BY [Project2].[PartialTag] ASC, [Project2].[TechnologyID] ASC, [Project2].[ITRackID] ASC, [Project2].[ITServerID] ASC, [Project2].[ITVirtualMachineID] ASC, [Project2].[TechnologyID1] ASC, [Project2].[ITRackID1] ASC, [Project2].[ITServerID1] ASC, [Project2].[ITRackID2] ASC, [Project2].[ITServerID2] ASC, [Project2].[TechnologyID3] ASC, [Project2].[ITRackID3] ASC, [Project2].[ITServerID3] ASC, [Project2].[ITRackID4] ASC, [Project2].[ITVirtualMachineID1] ASC, [Project2].[ITServerID5] ASC, [Project2].[ServerID] ASC, [Project2].[ITServerID4] ASC, [Project2].[ITRackID5] ASC, [Project2].[ITServerID6] ASC, [Project2].[ITVirtualMachineID2] ASC, [Project2].[ITRackID6] ASC, [Project2].[TechnologyID2] ASC, [Project2].[AssetTypeID] ASC, [Project2].[TechnologyID4] ASC, [Project2].[TechnologyID5] ASC, [Project2].[C1] ASC',N'@p__linq__0 nvarchar(4000),@p__linq__1 nvarchar(4000)',@p__linq__0=N'',@p__linq__1=N''
```

but what I have noted is that inside the Sql profiler query there are many OrderBy calls , so not sure if this is just the entity framework syntax, or there will be multiple OrderBy generated inside the DB from my action method orderby ,

```
OrderBy(a => a.Technology.PartialTag)
```

which might affect performance ? can any one advice ?

Comment: Entity Framework might be better than most developers at figuring out how to convert your LINQ into optimized SQL.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952147/entity-framework-include-orderby-random-generates-duplicate-data/8168872#8168872

Comment: @Cupcake can you explain your answer in more detials please?

Comment: @slavoo thanks for the link , but i got lost if EF is ordering the data only using the PartialTag column as mentioned on my "OrderBy(a => a.Technology.PartialTag)" OR it will do multiple OrderBy statements ?