# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Next()' method

Tags: c#, linq

I write this method :

```
 var resultVideos = (from video in db.Tbl_Videos
                            where channelName != "" ? video.Tbl_Categories.Tbl_Channels.Title.Equals(channelName) : true
                            select video)
                           .Where(video => categoryName != "" ? video.Tbl_Categories.Title.Equals(categoryName) : true)
                           .OrderBy(video => random.Next()).Take(8);
```

i know that provider can not  convert them to expression tree, so i try this:

```
 .OrderBy(video => (int)random.Next()).Take(8);
```

But it doesn't work, what is the solution?

Comment: How would the EF provider translate an arbitrary method call into SQL?  What SQL would you expect for this? If you just want a random order, see the possible duplicate.

Comment: Try `.ToList().OrderBy(video => random.Next()).Take(8);` instead of `.OrderBy(video => random.Next()).Take(8);`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth taking a look at the answers below:

- [Linq to Entities, random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order)
- [EF Code First: How to get random rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781893/ef-code-first-how-to-get-random)
- [Entity Framework Include OrderBy random generates duplicate data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952147/entity-framework-include-orderby-random-generates-duplicate-data)

To summarise it looks like you want to use `OrderBy(video => Guid.NewGuid())` instead of `OrderBy(video => rnd )`. However, other users have said this causes filtering to be done client side so I'd keep that in mind!