# ToList() incorrect evaluation when using Include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Consider I have the following snippet:

```
IQueryable<BaseEntity> someQueryble = ApplicationDbContext.BaseEntities;
var randomQueryable = someQueryable.OfType<RandomEntity>()
                                   .Include(prop => prop.SomeRandomNavProp)
                                   .OrderBy(prop => prop.Id);
```

`BaseEntities` is just `DbSet` from `ApplicationDbContext` from EF 6.
`RandomEntity` inherits from `BaseEntity` (Table-Per-Type hierarchy)

Then, something strange happens:

```
randomQueryable.Take(10).Count();
10
randomQueryable.Take(10).ToList().Count;
20
```

When `Include` is removed, everything works fine. Why does `.include` affect on `ToList` and how can I resolve that?

Edit: the generated SQL:

http://pastebin.com/SS3WD7P6

**Attention** - it's from production datababase, so readability can hurt. First query is about `Count` and the second one - about `ToList()`

Comment: Just want to confirm, you're certain you're using EF6 and not EF Core? Core has a few similar looking bugs to this.

Comment: @cost, no, EF6 for sure.

Comment: Would help if you enable logging (ApplicationDbContext.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine) and share the output in both cases.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Apparently the `Include` is ignored in the first scenario, but in my test `ToList` with `Include` also works. Anything unusual not shown there?

Comment: @IvanStoev try as `NoTracking`. I am preparing output right now for queries.

Comment: Nope. It just works :-)

Comment: This is hard to reproduce with the given information. Can you create a [mcve] including relevant models, context and configuration? What data is _in_ the list if you remove the `Count()`?

Comment: @IvanStoev and what about `OrderByDescending(k => Guid.NewGuid())` instead of showed one?

Comment: Ha, that definitely is the key - the `Include` internally uses `ORDER BY` for correctly correlating the data, so it requires deterministic ordering.

Comment: @IvanStoev Hmmmmm - usually `Take` throws error when non-deterministic order was applied.. Qustion is.. how to get ten random records from DB with `Include` clausule... Can it be possible?

Comment: Although this also works in my test. We really need to see the generated SQL with `ToList` call. Basically the output of `randomQueryable.Take(10).ToString()`.

Comment: @IvanStoev see output SQL (edited question). It will hurt (it's big, nasty etc) :)

Comment: Man, that's a huuuge query! Could you verify if it works correctly w/o random ordering (although I guess that's the idea)?

Comment: Really hurts :) But I see it basically does "select top 10 ... UNION ALL select top 10 ..." so no wonder you have 20 records. Why it does that is another story though, cannot have a clue for such huge query. Is it really produced by exact LINQ query you provided?

Comment: @IvanStoev - when Guid.NewGuid() is replaced with property  (f.e entity.Id), it... works. No idea why Guid.NewGuid() prodces strange result. So question is - how can I reimplement it - getting random rows with `Include`...

Comment: @Evk nice catch! Yep - only 7 Includes, OrderByDescending(k => Guid.NewGuid()) and Take.. No more (entities are just more complicated than showed above).

Comment: Ahh. Seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952147/entity-framework-include-orderby-random-generates-duplicate-data

Comment: @pwas Yep, that's exactly the same. No good solution though - I guess you are trying to page on `IQueryable`? If not, i.e. if you are going to materialize the result, then some loading tricks instead of `Include` might help. Let me know if that's the case, but probably that should be a different question.

Comment: @IvanStoev - yes, paging is done on IQueryable. But what is more - I have chnaged ordering function. See my answer :) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Evk and @IvanStoev found a nice post about ordering by `Guid.NewGuid()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8140495/5417374

Replacing order function with the following extension method solved problem (based on other answer in mentioned question):

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<BaseEntity> Randomize(
                         this IQueryable<BaseEntity> queryable)
{
    var seed = Random.NextDouble();

    return queryable.OrderBy(o => SqlFunctions.Checksum(o.Id * seed))
                     .ThenBy(o => o.Id);
}
```