# how to get random rows in linq with last inserted row on top

Tags: linq, entity-framework, random, linq-to-sql, shuffle

i am trying to show random products in view for each request, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7781899/2218697) `OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid())` works fine, but i am trying to increase perfomance when table records are huge , so i used second option from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/648247/2218697)

**my action:**

```
public ActionResult ProductType(string id)
{
List<ProductsView> productlist = (from a in this.dbo.ProductTable
                                 join ca in dbo.Category on a.CategoryID equals ca.CategoryID
                                 where ca.Category == id 
                                 select new ProductsView()
                                 {
                                 CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                                 Categorycount = c.Categorycount
                                 }).ToList<ProductsView>();

// here shuffle or mix products

int count = productlist.Count();
int index = new Random().Next(count);
ViewBag.Products = productlist.Skip(index).ToList();

 return View();

}
```

but when view returns some records are missing, eg:

**first request** 
count 4
index 1

shows 3 product in view

**second request** 
count 4
index 2

shows 2 product in view

**third request** 
count 4
index 3

shows 1 product in view

finally i have one more requirement can i show last inserted row in top and let other products be random ?

may i know what i am missing ?

any help would be great.

Comment: Well it's doing exactly what you've asked it to: it's skipping a random number of rows. Your requirements are really unclear here - what exactly do you mean by "random products"? If there are four products in total, how many do you want to display?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, actually i want to display 4 products but in random order for each request

Comment: Right, well that's not what your code says to do at all, is it? Random *ordering* is entirely different from skipping elements entirely. Do you always want to show all the products? What if there are thousands?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, yes you are right, but what can be done ? right now we are planning to display all products

Comment: Okay, so what do you mean by "last inserted rows in top" - how many do you want to be not-random? Just one? Everything in the last day? It sounds like you really need to think about your requirements very carefully before moving on to implementation.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, sorry for not saying the correct requirement, just one last added product should be at top and remaining random

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80162/discussion-between-stom-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the updated requirements are:

- Fetch all items
- Ordering is random other than the first item, which should be the last one added

Firstly, get rid of your `Skip` call. You're not trying to skip anything. Just fetch all the products (possibly ordered - see below) into a list.

For the randomness part, I'd do that in the calling code, using a modified Fischer-Yates shuffle - there are numerous examples of that on Stack Overflow, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287567).

In this case, you probably want to get the most recent item to the start of the list and then just shuffle the *rest* of the list. That's easy enough to do with a slight modification to the shuffling code - but you need to get the most recent item to the start of the list first. You could either do that by using `OrderByDescending(x => x.InsertionDate)` (or whatever) in your LINQ query, or just fetch everything and find the latest row in an O(n) pass over the rows in memory. Using `OrderByDescending` will be simpler, but potentially slightly less efficient (as you don't really need full ordering).

Comment: first thank you so much for helping me out, i am new using extention helper, may i know how can i use it is it this way in action method `exthelper.Shuffle(productlist,range);` how to get and pass random range parameter

Comment: @stom: You won't be able to use it as-is - you'll need to modify it to avoid moving the first element. I don't know what you mean by "random range parameter" - `rng` in my answer stood for "random number generator", not "range". See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx for things to be aware of when creating/using `Random`.

Comment: thank you , i will  check that and reply you in few days, really appreciate your time.