# Shuffle the results of a LINQ query based on SessionID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, pagination, shuffle

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application with Entity Framework 6 and a SQL Server database.

I'm trying to shuffle the results of a query by adding a `SortingCode` which I'd like to assign a value based on the current `SessionId`, so that every time the returned rows are shuffled without affecting the pagination. `SortingCode` in this attempt is a string, but it can be any type, as long as it allows me to get shuffled results. I have something like this:

```
var sessionId = Session.SessionID.GetHashCode();
var rnd = new Random(sessionId);

var query = (from l in _context.Adverts
             select new AdvertSummary
             {
                 Id = l.Id,
                 Title = l.Title,
                 Description = l.Description,
                 SortingCode = l.Title.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToString(),
             });
```

The `IQueryable` result is then converted into a list later on in my code with:

```
var pagedResults = query.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

The above attempt with the `Random` class doesn't work, and results in an error

> DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType

Is there anything that I can do to get shuffled results?

Comment: What is `_repository.MyTable()`? And what is `l.Title.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToString()` supposed to produce?

Comment: EF? Which version?

Comment: Many thanks for your attention. I've updated the post, hope it's clearer now.

Comment: There is solution how to [sort randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781893/ef-code-first-how-to-get-random-rows), but I also cannot understand why you sort characters of `Title`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv the solution in the post you linked uses `something.OrderBy(r => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5)`. Guid.NewGuid() doesn't work in pagination, as the order would be recreated at each change of page. I need to retain the same order while scrolling through the pages. That's why I need a sorting based on SessionID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `SqlFunctions.Checksum` for such task. `SortingCode` will be nearly close to the seeded Random.

```cs
var sessionId = Session.SessionID;

var query = 
    from l in _context.Adverts
    select new AdvertSummary
    {
        Id = l.Id,
        Title = l.Title,
        Description = l.Description,
        SortingCode = SqlFunctions.Checksum(sessionId, l.Title)
    };

var pagedResults = query
    .OrderBy(x => x.SortingCode)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(pageSize)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Svyatoslav, it worked, thanks a lot! I also had to add a change in my Global.asax.cs as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2874174/5740294), as my SessionID was changing at each request: 
`
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["init"] = 0;
}
`