# How to randomize collection of EF models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a User object that has a collection of Items.

How can I randomize the Items so they dont' appear in the exact same order everytime.

I'm currently ordering by SortOrder (integer), but this will obviously be in the same order everytime.

```
@foreach(UserItems ui in Model.User.Items.OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder))
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a little trick:

```
@foreach(UserItems ui in Model.User.Items.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()))
{

}
```

Comment: +1 for nice solution. But I am very curious how it is translated to T-SQL, do you know?

Comment: +1 for creative thinking

Comment: This may be sufficient for the asker's purposes, but it's important to note that this is not really random.

Comment: semi-random is fine.  Does it matter if the items are lazy loaded or eager loaded?

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları So whay didn't you do it in your answer? Something like this is working: **@foreach(UserItems ui in Model.User.Items.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()))**

Comment: @Alireza Take a look at this answer also. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4120132/205859. It looks like LINQ provider is able to translate it.

Comment: @user1361315 It shouldn't matter. Can you try it?