# Random order with Entity Framework and MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

**Summary:** I want to find a way to make random order with Entity Framework and MySQL (that's important). That solution shouldn't use raw sql queries or ordering AFTER loading all values from database.

**What I've tried:**

I took idea about using NewGuid() for random order from [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120132/596207).

Code:

```
var query = from e in context.Table
orderby Guid.NewGuid()
select e;
var test = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Always thrown exception:

```
An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
Inner exception:
FUNCTION MyDatabase.NewGuid does not exist System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}
```

Seems that problem is that MySQL doesn't have function NewGuid().

How can I order by MySQL function `RAND()` instead of `NewGuid()`. In other words, how to use custom function `RAND` in Entity Framework?

Comment: You have an Entity with a `Guid` as its PK and is trying to order by creating new `Guid`s? If that's the case, you should `order by e.NameOfYourId`.

Comment: @Tico, no, I don't have Guid field. My PK is integer with autoincrement. NewGuid() is function used (in that case) for random order. So every query result is diffrent. I took idea about NewGuid() from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4120132/596207

Comment: The static method `Guid.NewGuid()` creates a new valid `Guid`, so you're basically ordering your query in a condition that does not "works". I think that is better to List all your elements and then randomize them.

Comment: Che the **Edit (Current code):** from the question, it seems to be working.

Comment: check if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/648247/2998271) can help..

Comment: @Tico you used MySQL or MSSQL? If MySQL, can you say your version of server and version of Connector/Net?

Comment: @har07 thanks. Code in that answer using class `Function`. There is such class in linq-to-sql, but not in Entity Framework. Don't you know, maybe there are exists an analog for `Function`?

Comment: I use MSSQL, @Dador. I don't see a problem getting the data and them randomize it. Did you try the answers to the question you've posted?

Comment: @Tico, yes, of course. This works on MSSQL cause it has function [NewGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx), but MySQL doesn't have function `NewGuid`. Thought it have functions named [Uuid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) and [Rand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand). The question is how to use these functions in Entity Framework.

Comment: @Dador, I understood your question. The thing is: EF uses LINQ to create the TSQL for you. NewGuid is C# function, so - in theory - it should work. Try this: [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/sjusv8Ma)

Comment: @Tico, it works :) Almost that variant I'm currently use as workaround (difference that I'm using `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()`). The reason why I'm not use such variant constantly is that all rows from database loading to client instead of limited rows (for example 500 rows instead of 10). Anyway, thanks you for help with investigating this case.

Comment: My current project depends entirely on EF :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 4):

> Seems that problem is that MySQL doesn't have function NewGuid().

Call me lazy, but the problem seems to be that MySql does not have a function called NewGuid. So wouldn't the easiest solution be to create a function in MySql called NewGuid?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `NewGuid`() RETURNS char(36)
BEGIN
RETURN UUID();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Problem is solved for me after creating a MySQL NewGuid function.

Edit: The Questions states "solution shouldn't use raw sql queries" and this does not require a raw SELECT/INSERT statement. It does require the database function to be created though.

Extra note: I would say that this is technically a bug in the MySQL implementation. [Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are said to be "supported by all data providers" by Microsoft. NewGuid is listed under [Other Canonical Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738544%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I used this, and it worked, but there was problem with getting related entity with this. So i first get the random records, and then created another query to get related entity for random records.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query:

```
var query = from e in context.Table
            orderby SqlFunctions.Rand(1) 
            select e).Take(10);
```

And hope your MySql Data Providor cannot be recognized by VS.

I know that Vs doesn't support MySQL to LINQ directly.. So maybe you can use something like.

And perhpas you need to download this kind of data providor and have a try

download them and have a try:

1. [ALinq](http://www.alinq.org/download/ALinq_V2.5.8.msi).
2. [ORDesigner_VS2008](http://www.alinq.org/download/ORDesigner_V2.4.1_VS2008.msi) or [ORDesigner_VS2010](http://www.alinq.org/download/ORDesigner_V2.4.1_VS2010.msi).
3. [MySQL ADO.NET Data Provider](http://www.alinq.org/download/mysql-connector-net-6.3.0.zip) (If installed, no need to reinstall).

---

---

And  If you still fail, this can be right Suppose **Students** is a model from Student table

```
using (ConsoleApplications.DataClasses1DataContext dd = new ConsoleApplications.DataClasses1DataContext())
{
   var result = (from stu in dd.Students.AsEnumerable()
      select new
      {
       stu.StudentName,
       RandomId = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Next(dd.Students.Count())
      }).OrderBy(s => s.RandomId);

      foreach (var item in result)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item.StudentName);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the answer given by @Monkey Code but with a difference, the guid generated, despite random, was ordered and the quick solution for me was to use the following:

```
...
RETURN MD5(UUID());
...
```

Comment: It worked as it based on previous solution, but there was problem with getting related entity with this. So i first get the random records, and then created another query to get related entity for random records.

Answer (score -1):

This may help you

```
var yourRecords = context.Table().OrderBy(c=>c.Name);

yourRecords = yourRecords.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());
```

Comment: Please read the question. This variant works with MSSQL, but didn't works with MySQL.

Comment: Convert the results to a list so that you are no longer tied to the database. Then the order by guid will use linq2objects. `context.Table().ToList().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid());` Just make sure you limit the record set so you don't load too much data into memmory.