# Linq query causes null reference exception when accessing linked tables

Tags: c#, .net, linq

So I have the following linq query for a test blog:

```
var random = new Random();
var random = context.Blog.OrderBy(x => random.Next())
                         .Where(x => x.DisplayStatus == "Approved")
                         .Select(x => new Blog 
                          { 
                              Title = x.Title,
                              Content = x.Content,
                              AuthorId = x.AuthorId,
                              Author = x.Authors.AuthorName //null pointer exception here
                          }).Take(5).ToList()
```

The trouble is, it throws a null pointer exception when it hits 'x.Authors.AuthorName'. I cannot figure out why. I know the author is there because it works fine when I use linq expressions (from x in context.Blog ...etc), and it works in LinqPad. I can't use the linq expression, though, because I don't know how to declare 'OrderBy(x => random.Next())' without using a lambda expression.

this is the version that works without the random

```
var working = (from x in context.Blog
                 //NO known code to select random
                 where x.DisplayStatus == "Approved"
                 select new Blog 
                 {
                    Title = x.Title,
                    Content = x.Content,
                    AuthorId = x.AuthorId,
                    Author = x.Authors.AuthorName //NO null pointer exception
                 }).Take(5).ToList()
```

Blog is a POCO class with no database relations.
Authors is a database entity class with AuthorName being a simple string. 
Any idea on what is going on here?

Comment: The typo in `x.DisplayStaus` proves it's not copy/pasted code you claim is working. "Everybody lies" (c) Dr. House. So we ignore this claim. What value has `x` and `x.Authors` when you get NRE?

Comment: Can you try changing the name of the second variable to something that is not the same as the first one assigned to new Random()?

Comment: I don't want to actually copy paste my code because the full linq query is rather long. I put together a sample that describe the problem more succinctly. I did fix it if that bothers you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linq to Entities, random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
var working = (from x in context.Blog
                 where x.DisplayStaus == "Approved"
                 select new Blog 
                 {
                    Title = x.Title,
                    Content = x.Content,
                    AuthorId = x.AuthorId,
                    Author = x.Authors.AuthorName
                 })
                 .AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => random.Next())
                 .Take(5).ToList();
```

Edit:

I wasn't 100% sure what the error is and wanted to wait for the OP to check if my answer actually does what I believe it does.

I assumed that Entity Framework will not translate your query to SQL and therefor lose the ability to automatically load `x.Authors`, by moving the `OrderBy` the first "half" of the query, can be translated to SQL while the `AsEnumerable().OrderBy()` will run in memory.

So `AsEnumerable()` will force the query to be translated and exceuted in SQL, and the following `OrderBy` will run in memory.

Edit2:

About how to do it on the SQL Server and not loading the whole query to memory, I am afraid I can't help you with that, a google search brought this

[Linq to Entities, random order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654906/linq-to-entities-random-order)

Comment: This seems to be the solution. The trick seems to be to put .AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => random.Next()) at the end. I tried putting .AsEnumerable().OrderBy(x => random.Next()) before (from x in ...) but it only made things worse.

Comment: Your solution loads whole table to memory from DB, sorts it and takes 5 records.

Comment: What would be the proper solution then?

Answer (score 0):

I am not allowed to add a comment, so I ask here. What type is `Authors`? From the name I guess it could be some type of `Collection`.

What I often do if one Property might be `null` is to add a `?`:

```cs
Author = x.Authors?.AuthorName
```

Comment: Authors is a database entity type class. AuthorName is a simple string

Answer (score 0):

You can get random sort using `Guid.NewGuid()`:

```
var random = context.Blog.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
                     .Where(x => x.DisplayStatus == "Approved")
                     .Select(x => new Blog 
                      { 
                          Title = x.Title,
                          Content = x.Content,
                          AuthorId = x.AuthorId,
                          Author = x.Authors.AuthorName
                      }).Take(5).ToList()
```

Or [`SqlFunctions.Rand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.rand?view=netframework-4.8):

```
var random = context.Blog.OrderBy(x => SqlFunctions.Rand())
                     .Where(x => x.DisplayStatus == "Approved")
                     .Select(x => new Blog 
                      { 
                          Title = x.Title,
                          Content = x.Content,
                          AuthorId = x.AuthorId,
                          Author = x.Authors.AuthorName
                      }).Take(5).ToList()
```

Comment: Both of the yield: "NotSupportedException: This function can only be invoked from LINQ to Entities."
Blog is not an entity. I should have mentioned that.